# SyncFusion Xamarin: Auto generate PDF pages based on content

Tags: syncfusion

In Syncfusion for Xamarin, is it possible to create multiple pages based on the content? I am able to create multiple pages manually by:

```
//Create a new PDF document.
PdfDocument document = new PdfDocument();
//Add a page.
PdfPage page = document.Pages.Add();
```

I looked at multiple docs [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/getting-started) and [here](https://help.syncfusion.com/xamarin/sfpdfviewer/getting-started)
I know we can manually create pages but just wanted to know if we could auto generate based on the content in the PDF. if the content overflows could it create a new page automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can create the PDF document with multiple pages based on the content (allow the text to flow across multiple pages) using [PdfLayoutFormat](https://help.syncfusion.com/cr/file-formats/Syncfusion.Pdf.Base~Syncfusion.Pdf.Graphics.PdfLayoutFormat.html) in Xamarin Forms platform. Please refer the below documentation link for more details,

[Paginate the content in PDF document](https://help.syncfusion.com/file-formats/pdf/working-with-text?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=xamarin#creating-a-multicolumn-pdf-document)